# Semantic TextArea not editable with initial text

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

React Semantic  - TextArea

I have initial value  
which is showing in the textArea but its not editable anymore.

Any solution?

codepen example:

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/as3script/pen/VRepqv?editors=1010
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **state** for this purpose

```
    const { 
      TextArea,
    } = semanticUIReact

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          value: "initial text which I would like to edit" // set initial state
        }
      }

      onChange(e){
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
      }

      render() {
        const { value } = this.state;

        return (
          <div>
            <TextArea 
               rows={4} 
               style={{'width': '550'}} 
               onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)} 
               value={value} //render changed state
             /> 
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    // ----------------------------------------
    // Render to DOM
    // ----------------------------------------
    const mountNode = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(mountNode)

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode)
```